# Hard drives no longer work under Windows 10 but work under linux

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

**Although I would have liked to fix this issue, I ended up putting the data on 2 new drives and formatting the problem drives.**

2 of my hard drives just stopped working under Windows and pulling up disk management asks if I would like to initialize them, but I don't want to lose data. I can see them fine in Linux.  I've tried using [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) but that didn't seem to be able to resolve the problem. I'm not sure if gdisk for Windows can help me and the software warns that it's potentially destructive.

Does anyone know what to do?

-Edit-
Windows doesn't detect the disks so gdisk doesn't detect them. I'm going to have to find a way to get Windows to even see them before I can do anything. Maybe I'll try running gdisk on Linux.

[Here's a paste from boot-repair tool in Linux](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26237654/) - sdh and sdi are the ones with the problem.

[image]

Comment: If gdisk warns you like that its because there is an invalid but recoverable partition table.

Comment: That's what I suspect, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I don't want to say "go" and not have any specific options once I do. Is it ok to just let it decide what's best?

Comment: It looks like the disks were part of a mirrored RAID and now they are not.

Comment: They were never a part of any RAID configuration.

Comment: added a link to the boot-repair tool's output.

Comment: Although I would have liked to fix this issue, I ended up putting the data on 2 new drives and formatting the problem drives.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Testdisk (in Linux) to see if that can rebuild the partition table - https://www.geekyprojects.com/storage/how-to-repair-a-damaged-partition-table-or-mbr/

I suspect your disk is using MBR format rather then GPT format, so using GDISK is probably not the ideal tool for the job.  I've not done this particular operation but Testdisk can, as I understand it, Rewrite the MBR.

Comment: No, this isn't working either...